# Limpiar contenido cuyo tag sea el mismo

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo varias etiquetas `span` con la misma clase y estoy tratado de mediante una funcion que recorra todos los `span` y limpie su contenido.

He planteado esto pero no me funciona

```js
function limpiarError(){
    var spanTag = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

    for (var i=0; i < spanTag.length; i++){
        spanTag.elements[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<span id="errorId">1</span>
<span id="errorNom">2</span>
<span id="errorFecha">3</span>
<span id="errorTelf">4</span>
```

Answer (score 5):

`getElementsByTagName()` retorna un array, no un objeto que tenga una propiedad `elements`. Tambien tienes que ejecutar la función que no lo haces. En este ejemplo se ejecuta cuando la pagina carga:

```js
function limpiarError(){
    var spanTag = document.getElementsByTagName("span");

    for (var i=0; i < spanTag.length; i++){
        spanTag[i].innerHTML = "";
    }
}


window.onload = limpiarError();
```

```html
<span id="errorId">1</span>
<span id="errorNom">2</span>
<span id="errorFecha">3</span>
<span id="errorTelf">4</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Con jquery

```js
function limpiar() {
    $("span.test").html("");
}

setTimeout(limpiar, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test"> 123 </span>
<span class="test"> 123 </span>
<span class="test"> 123 </span>
```